# Dice Programm in C

Tags: c

I'm having some trouble with my homework and I hope someone can help me with it.
They want me to create a dice game with the following requests:

- 5 dice are rolled.
- Grand is what you get by rolling 5x the same number
- Poker for 4x the same number
- Full House for getting 3x the same number and another 2 with the same number aswell. example:(5,5,5,2,2)

I have written a code in which i can get some of the requests done. But I also have to save the values as an array which causes me alot of trouble. Can someone please show me how it is done? and explain it aswell? This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main () {

srand (time(0));



int dice[5];
int i;

    printf ("Program dice\n");

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    dice [1] = (rand ()%6 )+ 1;
    printf ("Würfel 1: %d \n", dice [1]);


    dice [2] = (rand ()%6 )+ 1;
    printf ("Würfel 2: %d \n", dice [2]);


    dice [3] = (rand ()%6 )+ 1;
    printf ("Würfel 3: %d \n", dice [3]);


    dice [4] = (rand ()%6 )+ 1;
    printf ("Würfel 4: %d \n", dice [4]);


    dice [5] = (rand ()%6 )+ 1;
    printf ("Würfel 5: %d \n", dice [5]);

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)

if (dice [i] == 5)
{
    printf ("You've won! Grand!");
    return (0);
}
else
{
    printf ("You lost.");
    return (0);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: after `int dice[5];` the 5 elements of the `dice` array are: `dice[0]`, `dice[1]`, `dice[2]`, `dice[3]`, and `dice[4]`. Notice there is no element `dice[5]`!

Answer (score 1):

First, let's take a look on how you generate the numbers... consider you are using an array, you can access it using the `[] operator`, it means that if you have an array, and you want to access the first element, considering that array index start from 0, you can do it by doing `array[0]` and since we are inside a for loop with a `i` that get values from 0 to 5, you can generate your dice roll with this

```
int dice[5];
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    dice [i] = (rand ()%6 )+ 1;
    printf ("Würfel %d: %d \n", i, dice [i]);
}
```

than, you have to create the logic behind each possible game win

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to restructure the code.
You should store the count for each dice roll. For example, `(5,5,5,3,3)` should generate `(0,0,2,0,3,0)`.
Now just use these instead.
Try this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
const int DICE_ROLLS = 5;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int number_of_rolls[6] = {0};

    // Simulate the random rolls
    for(int i = 0; i < DICE_ROLLS; ++i)
    {
        // Get a new roll ( from 1 to 6)
        int dice_value = rand() % 6 + 1;
        // If it is 1, increment rolls for number_of_rolls[0]
        ++number_of_rolls[ dice_value - 1 ];
    }

    // Now it is simple. To check for all five, do
    for(int i = 0; i < DICE_ROLLS; ++i)
    {
        if(number_of_rolls[i] == 5)
        {
            printf("You've won! Grand!");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully you get the gist now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I gave my students a similar question a while back. My solution can be found [here](https://github.com/alxhoff/Empty_C_Project/tree/yahtzee), although I only implemented checking for the same values (yahtzee/kniffel).

The code is written to be pseudo object orientated in that you have a `struct cup` that is [initialized](https://github.com/alxhoff/Empty_C_Project/blob/1c73aad2d2812ff86785ebb9584335dac752118d/src/yahtzee.c#L10) to store an array of pointers to dice object. The cup is then [filled](https://github.com/alxhoff/Empty_C_Project/blob/1c73aad2d2812ff86785ebb9584335dac752118d/src/yahtzee.c#L32) with a specified number of `struct dict`, found [here](https://github.com/alxhoff/Empty_C_Project/blob/yahtzee/include/yahtzee.h). Following that you can [roll the cup](https://github.com/alxhoff/Empty_C_Project/blob/1c73aad2d2812ff86785ebb9584335dac752118d/src/yahtzee.c#L61) which uses the `rand()` function to randomize values for each die in your cup.

```
int max_value = 0, dice_count = 0, ret;
struct cup *my_cup = NULL;

prompt_int("Please enter the max value of each die", &max_value);
prompt_int("Please enter the number of die in the cup", &dice_count);

my_cup = create_cup(dice_count);
fill_cup(my_cup, max_value);
roll_cup(my_cup);
ret = check_cup(my_cup)

switch(ret){
     //Respond[ to combinations
}
```

In the main.c you will find a function called `check_cup` in which you can put checking logic to check for certain combinations of dice, at the moment it just checks if all the dice are the same and returns 0, this could be modified to return certain values for certain.